# Getting "Enter Network Password" prompt on Windows 7 when clicking on embedded audio link

Tags: networking, windows-7, passwords, object-tag

We have a web app that shows a list of audio links to play. I've cleaned it up to just show the most basic page, without the Ajax calls or jQuery code:

```
<object >
  <param name="url" value="106.wav">
  <embed 
    src="106.wav"         
    controller="true" autoplay="true" autostart="True" />
</object>
```

The rest is a very simple web page. The issue we're having is that when clicking on this audio link in a Windows 7 system with an IE8 browser, the user gets an "Enter Network Password" prompt. They will get this prompt every time they click on it, regardless of whether they enter their credentials or not. This issue was just noticed a few weeks ago, though they were able to access these links without a prompt before, from the Windows 7 system. We originally thought it was a code change, but after stripping the page to what you see above and still having the issue it shows that it's independent of our code and was probably introduced by a recent Windows 7 update.

When these users log in from an XP system they're able to listen to the audio and do NOT get the prompt. Also, if the user has QuickTime as their default audio player then the above link works fine in Windows 7, without prompts, so it seems that it's the Windows 7 and Windows Media Player combination that is causing this "Enter Network Password" prompt. Another part of this puzzle is that if the user is an admin on the server where the web app is, then they do NOT get the prompt. Obviously we can't make all the users Admins on the server to resolve this :)

I hope I've included enough information. Has anybody run into anything like this? Anybody have any idea how we can get around this? Thanks in advance. Ben.